# Image is not shown from functional component to class component in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

My **button.png** file is in the public folder.

**HelloButton.js** in `src/components`:

```
import React from "react";

function HelloButton() {
  return (
    <a href="">
      <img
        style={{ height: "50px" }}
        alt=""
        src="/button.png"
      />
    </a>
  );
}

export default HelloButton;
```

**Header.js** in `src/components`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import HelloButton from "./HelloButton";

export default class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <div>
       <HelloButton />
     </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Even though there are no errors, but the image is not visible in the result.

Comment: Hi, You should not put your images in the public folder rather put them in the src folder and create a separate folder called images then store all your images in there.

Comment: Then import your image then rather pasting the location in the src attribute. Like this: import  nameOfImage from "./images/nameOfImage.png"

Comment: then paste it in your src like this: src={nameOfImage}

Comment: It works well in an [example in Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-rgb-ygfuph?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /button.png which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

Answer (score 1):

This is the right way to import image in src

```
import React from "react";
import BUTTON fro "./button.png" // correct absolute path

function HelloButton() {
  return (
    <a href="">
      <img
        style={{ height: "50px" }}
        alt=""
        src={BUTTON}
      />
    </a>
  );
}

export default HelloButton;
```

Comment: it throws 1 warning and 1 error from webpack

warning: Line 2:8:  'button' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './button.png'

Comment: after removing . from the path i get
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /button.png which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers which helped me

Solution was moving ***button.png*** file from public folder to ***src/images***

and edited HelloButton.js to

```
import React from "react";
import button from "../images/button.png"

function HelloButton() {
  return (
    <a href="">
      <img
        style={{ height: "50px" }}
        alt=""
        src={button}
      />
    </a>
  );
}

export default HelloButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

import image  like that

```
import image from "./assets/image/icon.jpg"
```